# Can you stack wait delay threshold for a multi signature transaction?

Tags: permissions, msig

If for example you have an account with a permission level that has:

- threshold of 11
- 11 accounts with 1 weight each
- 3 day delay with weight of 2
- 7 day delay with a weight of 4

Would you be able to add a `delay_sec` of 7 days in seconds and only require 5 accounts to satisfy the threshold?

In other words 5 accounts with a weight of 1 each = 5.  Add weight of 2 for 3 day weight plus a weight of 4 for a

Answer (score 0):

Yes in this case the wait permissions stack as do all other permissions that are satisfied.

One may see the code for this here https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/26a4d285d0be1052d962149e431eb81500782991/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/authority_checker.hpp#L206

Also note that the delay does not begin until the minimum threshold is met.

So the 7/3 day delays begins when 5 accounts have signed.